# Nvidia configuration file

Tags: nvidia, xorg, configuration

i'm tring to configure Nvidia powermizer using the xorg.conf. but that made applications crash so does Nvidia use the xorg.conf or it uses another file ?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced something similar in the past while trying to access the OpenGL/GLX configuration in NVIDIA X SERVER SETTINGS. The application crashed, and after a while I rememembered I got some error messages while updating nvidia driver. I simply ignored the messages and finished driver update. After a few days I just reinstalled nvidia driver, the proper way, no error messages this time.

PowerMizer should activate by itself automatically, but if it does not, you can check the box for POwerMizer located in NVIDIA X SERVER SETTINGS - Nvidia settings configuration - which is the last entry in  NVIDIA X SERVER SETTINGS tool. After that you can move up to the PowerMizer entry to see what happens. It should work fine unless you played with NVIDIA X SERVER SETTINGS, and checked extra options that your video card does not support.

FIle xorg.conf is generated automatically and correctly only if you type in a terminal this code:

sudo nvidia-xconfig

This command will override the previous file, back it up, and generate a new xorg.conf with the default settings. You should also check if the power manager package for your configuration and the screensaver utility are both installed and working fine on your system.